# Error with inserting data into SQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm creating a sign up page for a school program using Java. I have created a table with 3 users(Admin, Student Leader & Student) into the database by default. Now any students are able to sign up with their own username & Password. I tried to insert the text input by the users into the database table but the error is "org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: username)", i don't really get why is there missing database.
This is my code:

```
        JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //declare variables
            String username = "";
            String password = "";
            String name = "";
            String AdminNo = "";

            //get values using getText() method
            username = txtUsername.getText().trim();
            password = txtPassword.getText().trim();
            name = txtName.getText().trim();
            AdminNo = txtAdminNo.getText().trim();

            if(username.equals("") || password.equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name/Password is wrong");
            }
            else //Insert whether query is running properly
            {
                Connection conn = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

                String IQuery = "INSERT INTO Login(Username,Password,Name,AdminNo)" + "VALUES(username,password,name,AdminNo)";
                System.out.println(IQuery); //Print to console
                System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database");

                try {
                    ((Connection) conn).createStatement().execute(IQuery);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } // select the rows



            }

        }
    });
```

And this is my Database Table:
[Login Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEJ09.png)

Comment: I guess you want: "INSERT INTO Login(Username,Password,Name,AdminNo)" + "VALUES('" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + name + "', '" + AdminNo + "')";. But I suggest to read up on SQL-Injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the query that you are trying to execute:

> ```
> INSERT INTO Login(Username,Password,Name,AdminNo) 
> VALUES(username,password,name,AdminNo)
> ```

This is invalid. The `username`, `password`, `name`, `AdminNo` variables in your Java code don't get magically inserted into the query string.
You have to insert them yourself.

To do it right, you should use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;

String sql = "INSERT INTO Login (Username, Password, Name, AdminNo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

try {
  statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  statement.setString(1, username);
  statement.setString(2, password);
  statement.setString(3, name);
  statement.setString(4, adminNo);
  statement.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (statement != null) {
    try {
      statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Small note: in the above code I renamed your `AdminNo` variable to `adminNo`, because this is the recommended naming style in Java for variable names (known as "camelCase").